# How to get email from twitter on Android?

Tags: android, twitter

That permission in the my Twitter apps panel:

[image]

Here is the code which tries to pull the email:

```
twitterAuthClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<String> result) {
        Log.d("wtf", " email = " + result.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException e) {
        Log.d("wtf", " email = " + e.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Confirm the authorization, you are prompted for permission to provide e-mail, but the answer is:

> Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be whitelisted. See https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials and submit the request.